# assignment prob flow network solution

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

I have an assignment problem with cost matrix C, eg:

21 30 26 16 20
27 29 28 20 38
39 25 21 19 23
28 24 30 29 16
30 33 32 17 31

where C[i][j] means cost for worker i to do job j.

How can I solve this with a network flow algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are still looking for a solution, you can solve this as a [Minimum-cost flow problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_cost_flow_problem):

1. Create a source node connected to your N workers by edges with
   capacity 1 and cost 0
2. Connect each worker i to each job j by edges of capacity 1 and cost C[i][j]
3. Finally connect each job to a sink node with edges of capacity 1 and cost 0

Your problem is equivalent to minimizing the cost of pushing N flow units through the network from source to sink.

Comment: Is there a way to implement a push-relabel algorithm to solve this?

Comment: @mrjames Push-relabel works for simple maximum flow problems (i.e. without costs). A 'cost-scaling' algorithm is what you would need to use. Check out [this page](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.854/06/scribe/s12-minCostFlowAlg.pdf) for how it works. Otherwise you can find a review of different minimum-cost flow algorithms [here](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~jliu36/621_Paper.pdf).